# What is in the assembly registers before they are used in program?

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers

what is in the assembly registers before they are initialized ? If i am working with logic operands like AND, OR, XOR and only use it for example like this: `and al,00000000b` or `and al,11111110` what will be the value in AL register ?

Comment: **In what context?** Are your coding an operating system kernel, some UEFI firmware, or a Linux application? This could be related to your [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) and your [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) and your [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system). **Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65324348/edit) your question to improve it *a lot***

Comment: The first one obviously gives zero, no matter what is in `al` to start with.

Comment: And usually, assembler code is called from some C code, or generated by some compiler (e.g. [Ocaml](https://ocaml.org/) or [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...)

Comment: its aplication for school project, and just want to know if there is difference if i previously didnt use AL register in code and now i will just use command 'and al,11111110' if the register would behave as if it were zero.

Comment: Depends on the register and depends on the environment. Is your assignment meant to run on baremetal or within a particular operating system?

Comment: we are using visual basic for programing and i think it should run on 32bit intel processors

Comment: When the program doesn't know what is in the registers, we call them uninitialized, which is another way of saying they hold meaningless garbage.  Just like RAM and disc, there are a fixed number of bits with values, but many have no useful meaning, in particular, those that are unallocated to some purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Unless your code is the very first instruction the machine runs after power-on (i.e. the firmware in ROM or flash), it will have been called from *some* other code that left something in registers.

In some cases (like the OS starting a fresh process), it may choose to zero all the registers before switching to user-space to avoid leaking any kernel information that might have been left in registers.  (e.g. Linux does this on execve).

Registers are like global variables, but *truly* global across processes.  They always have some value.  In most cases you can't assume anything.  `and al, 1` might produce 0 or 1, you don't know; it depends on what "random" garbage was left in the low bit of EAX / RAX before your code ran.  It's usually not truly *random*, but it might as well be because there's no rule that governs what's allowed to be there.  e.g. it might be an address that some other code was using for something, or some data it was copying around.

**It might be useful to consider what state your program will *leave* the registers in.**  e.g. when your program exits to the OS.  Or for a function that returns, what values are in the call-clobbered (volatile) registers:  Other than the return-value in EAX (if you return a 32-bit integer or pointer), you can leave anything you want in ECX and EDX.

For the code you're returning to, the register state of regs that aren't call-preserved is basically the same situation as at the top of your function: it can't assume anything because some other code could have left anything.